# Uncheck the checked input when clicked on close icon for same label name for both input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So far what I did was when the user clicks the label,the checkbox of that label is checked and the value of the label is appended in another div along with close icon.When we click the close icon or uncheck,the checkbox will be unchecked.But when we have same label name for two checkboxes,on clicking the close icon or unchecking for one,both the checkboxes are unchecked because of the same label as both will be active.I hope you are getting what i am trying to say.Here is the code snippet for you to be more clear.Any help will be appreciated.

```js
var passed_value, data, input_value, checkbox_items;
$('.form-check-label').click(function(e) {
  data = $(this).text().trim();
  input_value = data.split(' ').join('_');
  $(this).prev('input').attr({
    'value': input_value,
    'id': input_value
  });
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    passed_value = $(`<div><span>` + data + `</span><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>`).prop('title', data);
    $('.result-text1').append(passed_value).css('cursor', 'default');
  } else {
    $('.result-text1 span:contains(' + data + ')').parent().remove();
  }
})
var active_text;
$('body').on('click', '.result-text1 i', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
  var text_div = $(this).prev().text();
  // console.log(text_div);
  active_text = $('.form-check-label.active:contains(' + text_div + ')');
  if ($(active_text)) {
    $(active_text).removeClass('active').prev().prop('checked', false);
  }
})
```

```css
.result-text1 div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
}

.result-text1 div span {
  color: #1e699b;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #1e699b;
  border-radius: 7px;
  // margin-right: 7px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 110px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

i {
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #2d84d7;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cd3112b74c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="card">
   <article class="card-group-item">
      <header class="card-header">
         <h6 class="title">pickup time </h6>
      </header>
      <div class="filter-content">
         <div class="card-body">
            <form>
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               morning
               </span>
               </label>
               <!-- form-check.// -->
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               afternoon
               </span>
               </label>
               <!-- form-check.// -->
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               evening
               </span>
               </label>
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               night
               </span>
               </label>
               <!-- form-check.// -->
            </form>
         </div>
         <!-- card-body.// -->
      </div>
   </article>
   <!-- card-group-item.// -->
   <article class="card-group-item">
      <header class="card-header">
         <h6 class="title">drop time </h6>
      </header>
      <div class="filter-content">
         <div class="card-body">
            <form>
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               morning
               </span>
               </label>
               <!-- form-check.// -->
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               afternoon                               </span>
               </label>
               <!-- form-check.// -->
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               evening
               </span>
               </label>
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               night
               </span>
               </label>
               <!-- form-check.// -->
            </form>
         </div>
         <!-- card-body.// -->
      </div>
   </article>
   <!-- card-group-item.// -->
</div>
<!-- card.// -->
<div class="result-text1"></div>
```

Comment: is there any specific reason to set value & id of a checkbox whenever user clicks on label? You can set the id & value of checkbox at the time of designing only which in turn gives you flexibility to have different value & id for "Pickup" & "Drop" options. And once the value & id are different then you can alter your javascript to work on the basis of those checkbox value & id rather the label text.

Comment: Oh , so you meant instead of checking the label,I should check for the id associated with that label when we uncheck or click on close icon as ids are unique??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unique `id` for checkbox and `for="id"` so that the checkbox works even if the label or span is clicked.
Since the similar property seems to be present multiple times assign them with a significance data-attribute or something.

Please check the code snippet below and leave a comment if your requirement is different.
Some changes I have applied are listed here,

- use unique `id` for checkbox and `for="id"` for `label` or `span`
- used `data-id="id"`(`data-attribute`) which helps in data manipulation
- use `let` instead of `var` since they are declared locally instead of globally
- use `.off()` ( i.e. `.off('click')`. Unbinding events is better
- check if the checkbox is checked or not before appending/binding the data in another `div` element
- it's better to call a event after a successful bind of data if data is binding from `js` `eventListener()` in this code snippet

```js
$('.form-check-input').off().on('click', function(e) {
    let id = $(this).attr('id');

    data = $(this).next('span').text().trim();
    input_value = data.split(' ').join('_');
    // $(this).prev('input').attr({
    //     'value': input_value,
    //     'id': input_value
    // });
    //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        passed_value = $(`<div data-id=${id}><span>` + data +
                `</span><i class="fas fa-times btnCross"></i></div>`)
            .prop('title',
                data);
        $('.result-text1').append(passed_value).css('cursor', 'default');
    } else {
        $(`div[data-id="${id}"]`).remove();
    }
    eventListener();
});

function eventListener() {
    $('.btnCross').off().on('click', function(e) {
        // e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        let $this = $(this);
        let targetEle = $this.parent().attr('data-id');
        $this.parent().remove();
        $(`#${targetEle}`).prop('checked', false);
        //var text_div = $(this).prev().text();
        // console.log(text_div);
        // active_text = $('.form-check-label.active:contains(' + text_div + ')');
        // if ($(active_text)) {
        //     $(active_text).removeClass('active').prev().prop('checked', false);
        // }
    })
}
```

```css
 .result-text1 div {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: min-content min-content;
        grid-column-gap: 5px;
    }
    
    .result-text1 div span {
        color: #1e699b;
        padding: 7px;
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #1e699b;
        border-radius: 7px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 110px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    i {
        height: 17px;
        width: 17px;
        background: #eaeaea;
        border-radius: 50%;
        color: #2d84d7;
        display: grid;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cd3112b74c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="card">
    <article class="card-group-item">
        <header class="card-header">
            <h6 class="title">pickup time </h6>
        </header>
        <div class="filter-content">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form id="pickupTime">
                    <label class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" id="ptMorning" type="checkbox" value="">
                        <span for="ptMorning" class="form-check-label">
                            morning
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <!-- form-check.// -->
                    <label class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" id="ptAfternoon" type="checkbox" value="">
                        <span for="ptAfternoon" class="form-check-label">
                            afternoon
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <!-- form-check.// -->
                    <label class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" id="ptEvening" type="checkbox" value="">
                        <span for="ptEvening" class="form-check-label">
                            evening
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" id="ptNight" type="checkbox" value="">
                        <span for="ptNight" class="form-check-label">
                            night
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <!-- form-check.// -->
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- card-body.// -->
        </div>
    </article>
    <!-- card-group-item.// -->
    <article class="card-group-item">
        <header class="card-header">
            <h6 class="title">drop time </h6>
        </header>
        <div class="filter-content">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form id="dropTime">
                    <label class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" id="dtMorning" type="checkbox" value="">
                        <span for="dtMorning" class="form-check-label">
                            morning
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <!-- form-check.// -->
                    <label class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" id="dtAfternoon" type="checkbox" value="">
                        <span for="dtAfternoon" class="form-check-label">
                            afternoon </span>
                    </label>
                    <!-- form-check.// -->
                    <label class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" id="dtEvening" type="checkbox" value="">
                        <span for="dtEvening" class="form-check-label">
                            evening
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" id="dtNight" type="checkbox" value="">
                        <span for="dtNight" class="form-check-label">
                            night
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <!-- form-check.// -->
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- card-body.// -->
        </div>
    </article>
    <!-- card-group-item.// -->
</div>
<!-- card.// -->
<div class="result-text1"></div>
```

Comment: Your code too is awesome. I had just kept the things like adding & removing active class as per the original question. And you added a click on checkbox instead of label.

Comment: Click on checkbox or span does the same thing  i.e. both is done to check/uncheck the  checkbox so we should apply the event for checkbox which makes easier to figure out if the checkbox is clicked or not.Your answer works fine @PrasadWargad what I tried is just to remove unnecessary codes.

Comment: Wow, such a simple and clean code.Thank you @Sushil.

Comment: @samanaghimire you cane make the above code more cleaner by removing unnecessary codes. Anyways thanks for your appreciation

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0e4756ub/2/

I have given id & value to checkbox at the time of designing only and using the same at the time of clicking on close icon.

JS:

```
var passed_value, data, input_value, checkbox_items;
$('.form-check-label').click(function(e) {
  data = $(this).text().trim();
  input_value = data.split(' ').join('_');
  var checkbox_id = $(this).prev('input').attr('id');
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    passed_value = $('<div><span data-id="'+ checkbox_id +'">' + data + '</span><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>').prop('title', data);
    $('.result-text1').append(passed_value).css('cursor', 'default');
  } else {
    $('.result-text1 span:contains(' + data + ')').parent().remove();
  }
});
$('body').on('click', '.result-text1 i', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
  var checkbox_id = $(this).prev().attr('data-id');
  if ($('#'+ checkbox_id)) {
    $('#'+ checkbox_id).prop('checked', false);
    $('#'+ checkbox_id).next('span').removeClass('active').prev();
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cd3112b74c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="card">
   <article class="card-group-item">
      <header class="card-header">
         <h6 class="title">pickup time </h6>
      </header>
      <div class="filter-content">
         <div class="card-body">
            <form>
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="morning-pickup" id="morning-pickup">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               morning
               </span>
               </label>
               <!-- form-check.// -->
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="afternoon-pickup" id="afternoon-pickup">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               afternoon
               </span>
               </label>
               <!-- form-check.// -->
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="evening-pickup" id="evening-pickup">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               evening
               </span>
               </label>
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="night-pickup" id="night-pickup">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               night
               </span>
               </label>
               <!-- form-check.// -->
            </form>
         </div>
         <!-- card-body.// -->
      </div>
   </article>
   <!-- card-group-item.// -->
   <article class="card-group-item">
      <header class="card-header">
         <h6 class="title">drop time </h6>
      </header>
      <div class="filter-content">
         <div class="card-body">
            <form>
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="morning-drop" id="morning-drop">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               morning
               </span>
               </label>
               <!-- form-check.// -->
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="afternoon-drop" id="afternoon-drop">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               afternoon                               </span>
               </label>
               <!-- form-check.// -->
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="evening-drop" id="evening-drop">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               evening
               </span>
               </label>
               <label class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="night-drop" id="night-drop">
               <span class="form-check-label">
               night
               </span>
               </label>
               <!-- form-check.// -->
            </form>
         </div>
         <!-- card-body.// -->
      </div>
   </article>
   <!-- card-group-item.// -->
</div>
<!-- card.// -->
<div class="result-text1"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.result-text1 div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
}

.result-text1 div span {
  color: #1e699b;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #1e699b;
  border-radius: 7px;
  // margin-right: 7px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 110px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

i {
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #2d84d7;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I will take a look at it :)

Comment: @samanaghimire checkout my answer if you want to minimize your code